# Wake-up PIC with USART RX

Tags: sleep, microcontroller, pic, wakeup, usart

I'm working with eXtreme Low Power (XLP) Microcontroller PIC 16LF1933.
For it to consume little battery, I put it to sleep until it receives a Break character (00h) in RX. The documentation explains well how to set the Auto-Wake-up with Break character in RX. I followed it.
I'm using Proteus to simulate the project, with Virtual Terminal to send information. If you press 
*CTRL + SHIFT + @* it sends de 00h (null/ all 0's), so, this would wake up the PIC, as said in documentation.
The problem is, when I do this, I receive a warning log saying that
`Wake up event is only 937.500003us wide. Minimum (at current baudrate) expected is 6.656ms. I'm using 9600 baudrate.`
How do I make a proper Wake up event with RX?
My `while` code

```
while (1) {
    BAUDCONbits.WUE = 1;    //Wake-up Enable
    SLEEP();

    while (BAUDCONbits.WUE);

    msg = Receive_Serial(); //Clear RCIF
    __delay_ms(100);
    msg = '\0';             //Discard
    __delay_ms(100);
    msg = Receive_Serial(); //Receive the next character
    __delay_ms(100);
    RCREG = 0;
    msg = '\0';
    __delay_ms(100);
}
```

And my Receive function

```
unsigned char Receive_Serial() {
    if (OERR) {                 //Overrun error
        RCSTAbits.CREN = 0;     //Fix reset Enable Receive
        RCSTAbits.CREN = 1;
    }

    while (!RCIF);

    return RCREG;
}
```

Comment: It is sometimes called a "break level signal" where the line is held at the `0` state for *more than* one character time, to distinguish it from a properly framed character. Your data sheet says "Therefore, the initial character in the transmission must be  all ‘0’s. This must be ten or more bit times, 13-bit times recommended for LIN bus, or any number of bit times for standard RS-232 devices." Though how you should transmit that break level signal, I don't know, but sending a `0` data byte will not, as you say, do it. For 8-bit data, sending `0` will hold the line low for only 9 bit times.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it really explains. Sorry that I didn't read this one part, it is right. I'll figure out how to send 13-bit times 0's.

Comment: Yes, but the warning log suggests it should be even longer? `937.5 us` is 9 bit times at `9600` baud (about 1 millisec), perhaps need to be 7 ms.

Comment: So, I'd have to send a 63 bit times 0's?

Comment: There should be a way to send a break level signal. Your PIC itself does have "13-bit Break character transmit", I don't know about the host.

Comment: With "host" you mean the device sending data? The project uses a Bluetooth module to receive data from a Android Phone. Will that be possible with that?

Comment: Actually, Android sends informarion via OutputStream. Which sends with (I guess) the Write method a array of bytes (byte[] msg), so I think it may work.

Comment: You cannot send long breaks unless the bluetooth module allows to swich to lower baud rates (<=1200) on-the-fly. Remember that the stop bit is a `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message you get is simply due to the fact that a null character (00h) is NOT a break condition.

Your pic code may be fine but the dev tool is not generating the correct test data.

Long long ago, I was once desperate to send a break to wake up a piece of dormant equipment and needed to send it a break. My terminal could not send one. I had to get this working so a quick hack was to send a null character with the terminal set to a lower baud rate, and switch back to the correct baud rate.